# If $0<f(x)<g(x)$ and continuous there exists a constant $1 > λ$ that $f(x) < λ\cdot g(x)$?

Tags: functions, continuity

Let $a, b ∈ \Bbb R, a < b$ and let $g : [a, b] → \Bbb R, f : [a, b] → \Bbb R$ be two continuous function such that $∀x ∈ [a, b] $ $0 < f(x) < g(x)$.
Then, there exists a constant $1 > λ ∈ \Bbb R$ such that $∀x ∈ [a, b]$ $
f(x) < λ\cdot g(x)$

> **Question:**  Prove or disprove each of the claim

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: As showed by both answers, the statement is true. Ask yourself what happen if we consider $(a,b)$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is YES.

Let
$$
h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}.
$$
Then $h$ is well defined on $[a,b]$, continuous and $0<h(x)<1$, for all $x\in [a,b]$. Τherefore $h$ it attains a maximum, which is less than 1, i.e., There exists an $\xi\in[a,b]$, such that
$$
h(x)\le h(\xi)<1,
$$
for all $x\in [a,b]$.

So for all $\lambda\in \big(h(\xi),1\big)$, we have
$$
h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<\lambda<1.
$$
Equivalently
$$
f(x)<\lambda g(x), \qquad \text{for all $x\in [a,b]$}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $g(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, we can define $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ for $x\in[a,b]$. Then $h$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $0<h(x)<1$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Let $M=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}h(x)$ then there is an  $x_0\in[a,b]$ such that $h(x_0)=M$ by the properties of continuous functions on compact sets and so $M<1$. Now we have
$$h(x)<\lambda:=\frac{M+1}2,\ \ \forall x\in[a,b].$$
Hence we find a $\lambda<1$ such that $f(x)<\lambda g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.